# PHP Echo within paragraph doesn't work with all records

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a simple form, like this;

```html
<div class="formholder">
        <form action="column1.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="URL:" name="url" required=""><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Job Title:" name="title" required=""><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Job Site & Additional Details" name="details"><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit"><br>
        </form>
        </div>
```

That form is then handled by `column1.php` which contains the following PHP;

```
<?php
$url = $_POST["url"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$details = $_POST ["details"];
$timestamp =date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$text = "<a href='{$url}'>{$title}</a><br><br> ".($details)." <br> At: {$timestamp} <br><br><hr><br> \n";
$file = fopen("./data/column1.html","a+ \n");
 fwrite($file, $text);
 fclose($file);
?>
```

Then on the page I want to show the submissions I use this;

```html
 <p class="linktext"><?php echo file_get_contents("./data/column1.html"); ?></p>
```

The CSS for my `linktext` class is this;

```css
.linktext {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 1vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 2vh;
    padding-right: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.linktext {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
}
}
```

For some reason the echo works fine for the first result but as soon as the second submission is sent, it won't be displayed correctly.

The file containing the responses looks like this after two submissions;

```html
<a href='URL'>Job Title 1</a><br><br> Job Details <br> At: Thursday 30th of May 2019 10:33:47 PM <br><br><hr><br> 
<a href='URL'>Job Title 2</a><br><br> Job Details <br> At: Thursday 30th of May 2019 10:34:00 PM <br><br><hr><br>
```

But shows this;

[image: A Screenshot of the error.]

I don't know why this has decided to not work given in other places, with the same type of form, the styling has worked just fine.

Any help would be appreciated on this because I'm stuck.

Comment: Odds are that your code is outputting malformed HTML. Can you post the actual list of links?

Comment: Try wrapping the whole snippet in `<div>` or `<p>`, or something else that is block level.

Comment: Hey, I've added the contents of `public_html` to download [here] (http://darkmode.16mb.com/public_html.zip), It has worked for me before but you're probably right. There's a working example up [here] (http://darkmode.16mb.com/run/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @prieber, it hasn't worked though. All code is available [here](http://darkmode.16mb.com/public_html.zip) or you can use the demo [here](http://darkmode.16mb.com/run/)

Comment: I've added style to the web version so it's more obvious @j08691

Comment: The HTML in your example is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Rather than;

```html
<p class="linktext"><?php echo file_get_contents("./data/column1.html"); ?></p>
```

I can just use;

```html
<div class="linktext"><?php echo file_get_contents("./data/column1.html"); ?></div>
```

It maintains all styles and will work based on the same CSS for the text class.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes for this code part:

```
$file = fopen("./data/column1.html","a+ \n");
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);
```

Attribute `"a+ \n"` is invalid. Use `"a+"` instead. And here you only writing. So `"a"` is perfect.

You do not any error management like

```
$file = fopen("./data/column1.html","a");
if (!$file)
{
    // error handling
}
else
{
    fwrite($file,$text);
    fclose($file);
}
```

If using `file_put_contents()` the code becomes shorter:

```
if ( file_put_contents( "./data/column1.html", $text, FILE_APPEND ) === false )
{
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: This is all helpful information, but it doesn't seem to be related to the problem in the question.

Comment: Agreed.  Good comments, but they didn't ask for a code review.

Comment: Appreciate the response, the PHP is functional so I'd like to leave it, just need the CSS to be obeyed.